# PHP remove html and php code from user input

Tags: php, html, post, input

I'm trying to remove any code that a user may have entered in the textarea. I've tried many things, nothing seems to work. Heres the code:

```
  function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
    if($invert == FALSE) { 
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
    else { 
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
  } 
  elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
  } 
  return $text; 
} 
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = nl2br($message);
$message = strip_tags($message);
$message = strip_tags_content($message);
$message = htmlentities($message);
```

Even with all of this, I can still put html tags and have them printed out and run as html. How do I remove all tags?

Comment: don't roll your own html cleaners, ESPECIALLY using regexes. you can **NOT** use regexes on html reliably. especially if that html is potentially bad/mis-structured. start using html purifier and get on with more important things.

Comment: html purifier still allows tags such as the bold tag and line breaks. I don't want those either

Comment: What is the input and output you currently are getting? You should run `nl2br` after the `strip_tags`.

Comment: @chris85 when the input is:' <a>dljsfkjhdsa</a><br><b><?php echo "good";;; ;::;""'"' <b>....?> hi the output is dljsfkjhdsa ....?> hi'   with ....?> in bold

Comment: Not what I am getting when using that function, see demo here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1db804d0eb9ac0da28559d96fb7dafb291ef8025

Comment: ... or use a secure php framework. Usually it's a bad idea to develop a full website completely from scratch. There's a high chance you miss something important. If you don't need a huge framework with numerous features, you can always use some micro framework (slim for example).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function.

**Example:**

```
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

or

```
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Comment: It works when I use just html tags but it doesnt work for everyting. For example when the input is: <a>dljsfkjhdsa</a><br><b><?php echo "good";;; ;::;""'"' <b>....?> hi the output is dljsfkjhdsa
....?> hi with ....?> in bold

Comment: I recommend just taking an in depth look at the `filter_input` function and it's various flags to work out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strip_tags](https://secure.php.net/strip_tags) function, it strips all HTML and PHP tags by default but you can allow some HTML tags (by example a, b, or span, useful in comments).

```
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
$message = nl2br($message);
```

or

```
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
$message = strip_tags($message, '<br><br/>');
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Strip_tags works well, even with the input _<a>dljsfkjhdsa</a><br><b><?php echo "good";;; ;::;""'"' <b>....?> hi_: http://3v4l.org/8m8iv

Comment: Don't know about downvote, but you should provide code in an answer. Not just a statement about what a function does. Also note that OP has this function in there code so perhaps it isnt working for them..

Comment: Not the hardest function to use, but okay. I've edited my first answer.

Comment: This is no difference though than OPs `$message = strip_tags($message);` and your answer.

Comment: I don't know how the OP is testing his code, but using only strip_tags gives the good result. No need for strip_tags_content or htmlentities function in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to remove any code that a user may have entered in the textarea. I've tried many things, nothing seems to work

But why you want to do that? It's not really the problem on input. If user entered i.e. `<script ....>` or `<h1>foo</h1>` it makes no harm. It's usually a problem on output (display) so I'd rather just call [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on data prior display to "neutralize" HTML tags

Comment: I thought about doing that at first, but the application in my case demands that I should be able to use html tags but not the user. This is actually from a user to user chat (facebook style), and I keep all the messages in a txt file. I need to put link to the user's profile, so this isn't possible.

Comment: You mean your code is using HTML tags? If so, how many tags are you using? Just `<b>` etc or anything possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTMLPurifier class. It is really simple to use.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Read the documentation!! Here is an example

```
function Sanitize_Inputs($inputs){
    require_once('.../HTMLPurifier/htmlpurifier.auto.php');
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = New HTMLPurifier($config);
    foreach ($inputs as $input_name => $valor){
        $inputs[$input_name] = $purifier->purify($valor);
    }
    $purifier=null;
    $config=null;
    return $inputs;
}


$sanitized=Sanitize_Inputs($_POST);
var_dump($sanitized);
exit;
```